# Add buffer with no overlap using `sf`

Tags: r, sf

Given a map, I am trying to add a buffer to the outer region; that is, the boundaries with **no** neighbors.

Unfortunately, the `sf::st_buffer()` method does not do the job.

Here is a reproducible example

```
library("rgeoboundaries")
library("sf")
library("dplyr")

map <- geoboundaries("USA", adm_lvl = "adm1")
map <- USA[USA$shapeName %in% c("Washington", "Oregon", "Montana", "Idaho", "Nevada", "Utah", "Wyoming"), ]
map_buff <- st_buffer(map, dist = 100000) # Buffer 100 km

par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(map$geometry)
plot(map_buff$geometry)
```

[image: Map]

My wish is, based on the image on the left, expand the map only in the colored areas (according to the corresponding states), whilst preserving the state division. However, the result I get is the image on the right.

Comment: So you do not want to dissolve the internal geometry of the states? If this is the case I would point out that the complicating factor is that you must also extent the vectors associated with each internal boundary. The outer buffer based on a single geometry is easy but the latter is quite difficult. To remove the internal boundaries and create the buffer take a look at `spatialEco::sf_dissolve` with y=NULL, then apply `sf::st_buffer` to the resulting object.

Comment: The easiest way might be to generate the buffer zone (just the outer part), rasterize it, assign raster cells to nearest polygon ID, then polygonize, then join to the original polygons and dissolve on polygon ID...

Comment: Where does the `rgeoboundaries` package come from? Its not on CRAN.